# Non-planar electrical circuit graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

[image]

In the following electrical circuit the textbook says it is non-planar. I was curious from a mathematics perspective on how to approach this and found Kuratowski's Theorem about having a K5 or K3,3 subgraph if it is non-planar. Can someone point out where the K3,3 subgraph is in this diagram? I am assuming it's not K5 since there are not 4 edges between each node. Also note for electrical circuits there is a node between each element. I am unsure whether the nodes in electrical circuits and the vertices in graph theory are equivalent

Comment: I think the graph actually is planar.  What sort of textbook are you referring to?  Could it be that the author is just referring to the particular embedding as non-planar?

Comment: While this particular drawing is non-planar, it's definitely a planar graph -- you can reroute the 8 ohm resistor right under the 5 and 4 ohm resistors, then reroute the 7 ohm resistor outside the 1 and 5 ohm resistors.

Comment: @ErickWong The textbook I'm referring to is Fundamentals of Electric Circuits by Alexander & Sadiku, I'm thinking the answer might just be wrong because from what Kyle Miller's comment says, it is clear that we can redraw this as planar

Comment: If the authors are physicians, they might not be aware of the subtle terminology difference between a "planar graph" (an abstract graph which *can* be embedded into the plane) and a "plane graph" (a particular embedding of some planar graph into the plane).

Comment: @Conor_Meise From what Google Books allowed me to glean, it really does sound like the book is referring to graph planarity (not being an expert on circuits, I'm not sure why it's a useful concept in that domain) and not about particular embeddings.  So yes, the exercise seems to be wrong, which does happen sometimes :).

Comment: @JeanAbouSamra - the authors are physicists. "Physicians" are medical doctors.

Comment: As a practical matter for finding $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ subgraphs, the former must have five nodes of degree $\ge 4$ in mutual contact. The latter must have two disjoint groups of three nodes of degree $\ge 3$  (six nodes total), with each member in contact with all members of the other group. In this case, there are only five nodes total, so it cannot have a $K_{3,3}$ subgraph, and there are only four nodes of degree $\ge 4$, so it cannot have a $K_5$ subgraph.

Comment: Sorry, “physicians” was a false cognate with my mother tongue (French).